# Do companies that get taken-over have to honour the old gift card/certificate?

Tags: gift-card, gift-certificate, shopping, legal-tender

With reference to [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/1279/do-gift-cards-expire-does-a-gift-certificates-value-depreciate-how-long-can-i), can companies that get taken over set limitations on honouring gift cards issued prior to the take-over?  Also if a company just changes it's name, can it set limits on the gift cards issued under the old name?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends completely on the nature of the takeover. When a business is bought, the new owner takes on the obligations of the prior owner, the debts don't just go away.
When a business files for bankruptcy, its debts may get discharged, and gift card holders can easily be the first ones to get nothing back. A case in point was Sharper Image who stopped honoring gift cards even while the doors were open as they filed for bankruptcy.